# jqueryui autocomplete doesn't work in php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

**Solution:**

The problem is that in my php code, I have a debug message: print $_GET['term'];
It also return the result to client.

I am implementing search with autocomplete feature, but hitting some issues when connecting to  php, here is my code

html:

```
<input type="text" id="leaderboard_search" />
```

search.js:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$( "#leaderboard_search" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        width: 240,
        source: 'search.php'
    });
});
```

search.php:

```
<?php 
    $values = array('abc','def');
    echo json_encode($values);
?>
```

When I type something. It just doesn't show anything. I have debugged into php code, search.php get called with no problem. So I suspect the problem is on jquery side.

I am using jqueryui 1.8

Update: to simplify the problem, I changed to embedded js, but still doesn't work:

html code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#leaderboard_search" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        width: 240,
        source: 'search.php'
    });
});
</script>
<html>
<fieldset class="searchinput"><input type="text" id="leaderboard_search" /></fieldset>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `jQuery(function($) {` ?

Comment: I am newbie, just saw someone use it. Can you tell me what should I use?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Also I want it in a separate file not embedded js code

Comment: @Incognito, I changed to embedded js code, still doesn't work

Comment: Is your PHP file executing PHP or are you just returning a page that says "echo" at the start?

Comment: Should be executing PHP, see my updated php code

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice. It's been a while since I used jQueryUI. Just have the search function aware of the fact it's an object and not an array.

Comment: @performanceuser , if you are a newbie , then you should learn javacsript first , instead of this ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

according to the jquery documentation here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

it states that the result either can be a name value pair or just an array or strings.. so instead u shud echo smthing like this.

```
echo '["abc","def"]';
```

Comment: try inspecting the response u r getting from the server.. by going to the developer tool "F12".. and look r u getting the values u should get in the response. if not.. the problem is on server side.. else problem is with the client side code

Comment: You rocks. The problem is in my php code I have a debug code that print out the array, After removing it, it wokrs

Comment: I don't know who did it. I have selected your answer and correct one.

Answer (score 0):

try this as your search.php:

```
$values = ['abc','def'];
echo json_encode($values);
```

Comment: Still no luck. json string is valid.